# Does Nexus S Wifi and GPS have issues?

Tags: wi-fi, gps, samsung-nexus-s, network-signal

So there I was, happily reading reviews about Google's/Samsumg Nexus S building my judgement whether to buy it or not after my Nexus 1 got stolen. Happily enough there were very few posts on issues with the phone and most reviews would state quite triumph for Samsumg for it's gorgeous screen and for finally getting rid of it's dreaded GPS bummer.

Decision made and finally got my own brand new NS. In general terms, the phone is pretty smooth, very responsive - haven't seem an android phone this smooth in a while. I'm pretty happy with it. However, there are two issues which are bugging a lot: the WiFi and the GPS. Since I've read these reviews I mention in the beginning I'm not too sure whether they design flaws or just I got (un)lucky with this one.

My GPS is definitely crap. I have that "GPS test app" and even when it has like 7 satellites in sight it still wont manage to get a lock as quick (if any) as other phones I've been comparing it. E.g. And old HTC Magic sitting next to my NS got a lock in like, 5 seconds while mine took almost 20 - then lost it. Also, after acquiring the lock, it has an average of 20-30 meters error while the HTCs and Nokias are like pin-point 5m<.

As for the WiFi, I'm not sure if is just a display issue or if the reception is really bad, but being in the same room as the router, about 4 meters away, the phone shows two strength bars only. I figure that the reception could be just fine and the display could be just bad parametrized so I've got the "WiFi Analyser" app it says my signal is at -78dBm (which with a little googling apparently means pretty weak).

What do you guys say? Are those known issues? Are there Fixes? Should I send it back?

I just reaaaaly don't want to root it get custom Roms and try and try.. This thing is brand new, should work as it is.

Comment: Yeah I am having the same issue. The GPS is crap and has errors as you said.

Answer (score 3):

If nobody else is having the issue, I'd send it back for a replacement.  You probably just got unlucky.  Though you might also want to compare the WiFi signal strength with your other phone, and try some speed tests to see if it's actually an issue or if the number of bars is just misleading.

Answer (score 0):

This link:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Mobile/thread?tid=72cde4a29b9021c3&hl=en

on the Google forums would indicate that there are some connectivity issues with the Nexus S